# Can I preload an image for a component before it gets used in nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm close to deploying a project with NextJS, however I noticed that a lot of the images take quite a bit of time to appear on screen.
I've installed sharp and set the priority to true, but even then images appear pretty slowly. 
There's one part of the application, where a specific component gets conditionally rendered. That component has a small illustration included (about 30-50kb depending on the type) and it only shows for 2 seconds, since it's a short confirmation for the user.
There's also another page, which has a bigger illustration on it (about 500kb), which I would love to preload, since it takes a good second to load, when the component gets rendered.
Basically what I'd like to do, is fetch the needed images/illustrations ahead of time, before they need to be used, so that they appear instantaneously for the user.

Is there a way to do this in NextJS? Also happy to move away from the Next/Image component and just use img tags to do this.

Not sure whether code helps in this case, but here is how I display the 500kb image:

```js
<div className="result__illustration">
   <Image
     src={resultIllu}
     alt=""
     layout="responsive"
     objectFit="contain"
     priority={true}
    />
</div>
```

Comment: Using [`priority="true"`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#priority) will automatically preload the image. You should try to optimize the image instead: smaller width/height and/or more performant image formats (avif or webp).

Answer (score 2):

This is possible using `new Image()` and then adding an src attribute to it. I made a simple example to illustrate a memoized version of this behavior:

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-ully-vdobj9?file=/src/App.js)

```js
const PreloadedImage = preloadImage("https://via.placeholder.com/700x500");

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <PreloadedImage alt="Placeholder image" />
    </div>
  );
}

function preloadImage(src) {
  const image = new Image();
  image.src = src;
  return function PreloadedImage(props) {
    return <img {...props} src={src} />;
  };
}
```